# Set Managed Metadata Value on SP2010 Item using JSOM

Tags: 2010, javascript, managed-metadata, client-object-model

Okay I am fairly sure that I've searched through everything, but I can't seem to figure out how to set a managed metadata value for an item using JSOM in 2010... Why can't we just upgrade to 2013... :(

I checked [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95933/add-list-item-with-managed-metadata-field-through-jsom) but it doesn't work for 2010, and I don't understand how to translate the 'ColumnName' and 'TextColumnName' variables from [this MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/11/18/how-to-work-with-managed-metadata-columns-by-using-the-sharepoint-client-object-model-kaushalendra-kumar.aspx)

I know how to lookup my taxonomy items in 2010 using the TaxonomyHiddenList, so I have access to the all the different associated fields.

If you'd like some parameters for an example, I'm trying to assign a list item a managed metadata term with the following info, which is from my TaxonomyHiddenList:

```
ID: 1
IdForTerm: "6f5fee88-7383-4ba3-a29b-835f9ccee3ed"
IdForTermSet: "e4ee16dc-59c8-4749-bb1d-65538bd20175"
IdForTermStore: "84cbda40-2537-444e-86bb-4f84926de202"
Term: "Term1"
Term1033: "Term1"
Title: "Term1"
```

My managed metadata field is a multi-value field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312518(v=office.15).aspx) was introduced in SharePoint 2013 CSOM API, so the example that you mentioned in the question is intended for SharePoint 2013 only.

### How to set Managed Metadata field in SharePoint 2010 JSOM

The following example demonstrates how to set single-valued Managed Metadata field value

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() {

     var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
     var listTitle = "<list title>";
     var taxFieldName = "<taxconomy field name>";
     var termLabel = "<term label>";
     var termId = "<term guid>";

     var context = new SP.ClientContext(webUrl);
     var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);            
     var item = list.getItemById(1);

     var termValue = "-1" + ";#" + termLabel + "|" + termId;
     item.set_item(taxFieldName, termValue);
     item.update();


     context.load(item);
     context.executeQueryAsync(
            function () {
                console.log('Item has been updated: ' + item.get_id());
            }, 
            function (sender, args) {
                 console.log(args.get_message());
            });

});
```

In case of multi-valued Managed Metadata field, the format of value is:

```
-1;#<termLabel1>|<termId1>;-1;#<termLabel2>|<termId2>;...-1;#<termLabelN>|<termIdN>
```

Comment: I thought I had tried this solution -- I found some other stuff that mentioned setting a 'hidden field' value in addition to this one, that's apparently not necessary but what's the deal with that? :)

Comment: Revisiting this: I came across a different list today where I needed to assign the value to a field that had a long random name (mine was `i8c02d9873d74d93a7a201363243bf64`) instead of the managed metadata field itself (which is just called `Topic`)